# fetch data in a different format from mysql databate

Tags: mysql, date

I saved data in this format `YYYY-MM-DD`. Now I would print out in a different format like this: `DD-MM-YYYY`. How can I do?I mean I need to save it in this format `DD-MM-YYYY` or I can save it in whatever format and retrieve it in established format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it helps

```
//php
$records =mysql_query("SELECT otherFields,DATE_FORMAT(dateField, '%d-%m-%Y) as time 
from tableName");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($records))
{
 echo"$row['time']";
 echo"$row['otherFields']";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only save in `YYYY-mm-dd` format but later while fetching, displaying you can convert it to any format. Check the [**DATE_FORMAT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function of mysql

You can also convert the date with whatever language you are using with mysql

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(my_date, '%d-%m-%Y') FROM ...
```